# Convert volume to STL file?

Tags: xtk

I pulled the rep from XTK/K. Now I am able to load my created NII files into the slicer with the thresholding method. Now I am able to threshold my pixel data within the volume object. Is it possible to convert the thresholded volume which is rendered into a STL file or similar? Can write such a file to the system?

Thanks in advance
regards Stefan